# Row header value given the Row and Column Nos of a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

If I click on a particular cell in a `table`, I am trying to get all the values of that particular column. Also if the cell value is not empty I am trying to get the corresponding row header for that cell. Below is the section of code that gets the cell value but does not take the row header value. Please advise.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    var value = $('#tablename').find('tr').eq(len).find('td').eq(colno-1).text();
    if (value !='0' || value !='') {                      
        var headervalue = $('#tablename').find('tr').eq(len).find('td').eq(colno - 1).parentNode.cells[i];
        console.log($(headervalue).text());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          for (i = 3; i < document.getElementById("mytable").rows.length; i++) {
                txt = $('#mytable').find('tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(colno-1).html();
                 if(txt != 0) {
                     headervalue = $('#mytable').find('tr').eq(i).find('.classname').text();


                }                   
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this through Javascript.

```
for (i = 0; i < table.rows[1].cells.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + table.rows[1].cells[i].headers + "<br>";
    if(txt !='') {
        txt = txt + table.rows[1].cells[i].innerText + "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope it doesnt work . I want to take all the column values and corresponding row headers for those values that is not zero